# Google Keep Not Syncing Notes

Tags: troubleshooting, google-keep

Google keep has stopped syncing all of my notes all of a sudden. Notes created on Android phone are not available on the web version and vice versa. It was working all fine till yesterday. The Google help was not of any help. Anything Else I can do? I have restarted, checked the sync settings and updates etc.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Found a way to fix this here ( https://www.thetechminute.com/fix-google-keep-not-syncing-notes-images/). It is a temporary solution though. Removing and re-adding the Gmail account associated with Keep account did the trick. But, it only stays for an hour so and the problem re-appears again. But, at least, I can sync my stuck notes and images for now.

Comment: There's one problem with this suggestion. If you have notes that you have added AFTER not syncing, you WILL lose them all the moment you remove your Google account. I faced that, losing more than 100 important notes with no way to recover. Your notes are tied to the account they were added to. So be vary if this fact.